# error when running the stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in mysql and below is the command:

```
create procedure insertIntoEMP (IN name1 VARCHAR (50),IN sal1 INT) 
BEGIN 
   insert into student values (name1, sal1) 
END;
```

But I am getting an error. I am running the above command in mysql client. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

Comment: Error message says your procedur have one more "e" as needed but it looks loke correct. Maybe remove the second space after create.

Comment: could you please elaborate. Or let me know if there in any error in the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `;` after `insert`:

```
create procedure insertIntoEMP (IN name1 VARCHAR (50),IN sal1 INT) 
BEGIN 
   insert into student(name, sal) values (name1, sal1) ;
END;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18c03/1/0)**</kbd>

Adding column list to `INSERT INTO tab(col_list) VALUES ...` is a good practice.

---

You may need to define [delimiter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html) depending on your client:

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program
>   containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. **By default, mysql
>   itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must
>   redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire
>   stored program definition to the server.**

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure insertIntoEMP (IN name1 VARCHAR (50),IN sal1 INT) 
BEGIN 
   insert into student(name, sal) values (name1, sal1) ;
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Still there is error:

 create procedure insertIntoEMP (IN name1 VARCHAR (50),IN sal1 INT)
    -> BEGIN
    ->    insert into student(name, sal) values (name1, sal1) ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
mysql> END;

Comment: @Pradeep Did you add `DELIMITER`?

Comment: how to add the delimmeter.

Comment: This is now working. Interested in knowing how did it solve. please explain. I am from java development background.

Comment: @Pradeep Added explanation